# How many times the CompareTo method is called when a collection is sorted?

Tags: c#, .net, sorting, collections, icomparable

If a type implements `IComparable<T>` and you have a collection of this type with 100 elements. When you call the Sort method on this collection, how many times would the `CompareTo` method be called and how? Would it be used in this manner?

```
CompareTo(item0, item1);
CompareTo(item1, item2);
CompareTo(item2, item3);
CompareTo(item3, item4);
...
CompareTo(item97, item98);
CompareTo(item98, item99);
```

EDIT: Basically what I am trying to do is to turn this way of sorting into a value-based sorting where I assign some value to each item and then sort them. It's hard to explain but I am not able to use a -1,0,1 based sorting function for this problem. But all I have is a CompareTo function that I need to use to sort the items. So I need to generate some values for each item, and then the program will sort them from the smallest value to largest.

Comment: That depends entirely on the particular implementation of IComparable<T>, doesn't it?

Comment: I don't think so, because CompareTo will always return -1, 0, or 1.

Comment: @mwilson Actually that would entirely depend on the `Sort` method (the algorithm used) and the data itself :)

Comment: It's dependent on the sorting algorithm and how unsorted the data is.

Comment: Are you trying to sort items where order is not defined for any 2 elements? Normal sort algorithm require comparison to be transitive (a < b && b < c then a < c), it sounds like you have comparison defined only between some of the elements - you may not be able to use normal sorting functions (and there may not be single defined ordering for your sets...)

Comment: The order of items is known but this program only accepts a property set on each item to sort them by this value. I haven't checked if it preserves the order if 2 values are the same, but basically I am trying to create such a property by turning this CompareTo method into a single comparable values across all items. Not sure if this is a common problem.

Comment: You mean something similar to what [OrderBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966.aspx) expects? Than it is quite common... Maybe just use `OrderBy` instead of Sort?

Comment: Thanks, exactly like that, but the comparison is not dependent on a single value, so I think I will need multiple of these.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well, you can't be 100% sure (with most sorting algorithms) as it will depend on the data.  For example, certain sorting algorithms will only perform N (N being the size of the collection) comparisons of the data is already sorted, but needs to be much more if it's not.

The commonly used sorting algorithms, such as MergeSort, QuickSort, and HeapSort are all O(n*log(n)), which is to say the number of comparisons will be on the order of the number of items times the log base of the number of items.  (The log base will be 2 for those algorithms.)  While this won't be exact, it will scale with that relationship.

If you're interested in how many times it's called for a particular sorting operation you can use something like this:

```
public class LoggingComparer<T> : IComparer<T>
{
    private IComparer<T> otherComparer;
    public LoggingComparer(IComparer<T> otherComparer)
    {
        this.otherComparer = otherComparer;
    }

    public int Count { get; private set; }

    public int Compare(T x, T y)
    {
        Count++;
        return otherComparer.Compare(x, y);
    }
}
```

It will wrap another comparer but also count the number of compare calls.  Here's an example usage:

```
var list = new List<int>() { 5, 4, 1, 2, 3, 8, 7, 9, 0 };

LoggingComparer<int> comparer = new LoggingComparer<int>(Comparer<int>.Default);
list.Sort(comparer);
Console.WriteLine(comparer.Count);
```

Comment: Does it really make a difference of which base the logarithm is? The O notation only calculates a relative number. I.e. it tells you how much more complex the operation is when you increase `n`, but it does not tell you how many basic operations are needed for a specific `n`.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes usually, nobody cares about the exact number of operations, just the growth pattern.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes It's all a matter of how detailed you want to get.  At the most basic level, big-oh would say not to define the base of a log, but it can be useful, in practice, to provide more information that big-oh normally includes, such as the base of the log.  How detailed you want to go depends on context.

Answer (score 1):

Piggy backing on Servy's answer. Whatever the Asymptotic Complexity for comparison operations of the sorting algorithm is, that is how many calls will likely be made to CompareTo(). Note, this is usually a growth pattern and not an exact number of operations.

Comment: kinda-sorta.  When determining the asymptotic complexity of an algorithm you generally state up front which types of operations you're considering "one unit".  For sorting algorithms this is generally only `CompareTo` calls, but it may (for certain algorithms) include other operations.  For non-sorting algorithms it could be...anything.

Comment: @Servy, even with your answer, you have to account for whether you are counting swaps or comparisons. Take the insertion sort for example. I am referring to comparisons though, as that is usually what is the most costly of the the sorting algorithms.